# PHP and Amazon S3 as a File Storage System for dynamic website

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a dynamic website on which users can upload different files to be reviewed by different experts.

Users can upload/download their files to/from our server.

How can I use the Amazon S3 and PHP to expand my storage? I already have an AWS account and made a research on the net, but i still can't figure out How to make sure that every user can access only his files and the one he will upload will be in a specific bucket with his username?

Comment: I have been studying the S3 php class developped by Donovan Schonknecht, which is actually a piece of art, but I think it does not match my needs because the files are stored in the same bucket and viewed only on the amazon console.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a separate bucket for each user. You should use one bucket per application/environment. To work with Amazon S3 you can use [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/). Your file "structure" will look something like this: `/{bucket}/{userid}/images/*`, `/{bucket}/{userid}/videos/*`, etc.